# Cannot connect to my VPN Server from another network

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, rras

ok here is the deal. I have a Windows 2008 R2 server with RRAS installed configured for VPN. I also have DHCP running. On my DC I have AD running and they're connected with my domain. I am only using one NIC though.

As a client I have Windows 7. So I tried connecting to my VPN server through my own network, which worked fine, so the setup is correct. However, when I tried connecting to my VPN server on another network, it does not work. I went to my brothers home and tried connecting to my server but it did not pass.

So on my VPN server I have ip: 192.168.2.99

At my brothers house, i did the configuration on his windows 7 and it cannot connect to that ip. I am operating on the 192.168.2.1 network and he is operating on the 192.168.0.1 network. So how do I configure his client in order to get it to work? I tried changing his ip to the 192.168.2.x network, but i am not sure you can do that. I need some help here what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> So on my VPN server I have ip:
>   192.168.2.99

With that address nobody can reach your VPN server from the outside.

Since you're going with a single-homed approach, you'll need to setup port forwarding on the firewall in front of the VPN server to send the RRAS traffic back to that server. Then, from the outside, you'd connect to the firewall's address for VPN.

This article may be helpful: http://blogs.technet.com/b/rrasblog/archive/2006/09/20/457653.aspx

Comment: +1, you need to make sure you have an external IP that forwards those calls to your RRAS server otherwise you'll never get connected. I've seen setps set as vpn.ourcompany.com.

Answer (score 0):

It may be his "internet connection device". If he has DSL or Cable internet check his modem\router\firewall for a "VPN passthrough" option and make sure it's enabled with the appropriate options: PPTP, L2TP, or IPSEC.

Comment: I have already opened port 1723 and  47.

If my brother has a 192.168.0.1 gateway, should I enter that info in my IP scope?

Comment: forgot to say that i am using VM ware, should I use bridge or nat?